# Local Bootstrap nav-tab works, but not remotely from github pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**EDIT:** Problem solved so I removed my Github link. Github pages require https secure connection for every script linked. Also always check console!

I am getting a weird bug where if I drag and drop my index.html into Firefox or chrome, the bootstrap nav-tab works and the tabs transition the tab-content when I click between the "Art" and "Resume" tab. But if I push my web page to Github pages and visit the page through Github and then click the other "Art" tab, it won't work. The link will change to "#Art" but the tab-content won't transition.

The code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/darkly.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/socialbuttons.css">  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li id="resume-tab" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Resume">Resume</a></li>
      <li id="art-tab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Art">Art</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content main-body">

        <div id="Resume" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div class="texts container">
                <p>resume tab</p>
            </div> <!--close container-->
        </div><!--close Resume-->


        <div id="Art" class="tab-pane fade images">
            <div class="container">
                    <p>art tab</p>          
            </div><!--close container-->
        </div> <!--close images -->
    </div> <!--close tab-content main-body -->

  </body>
</html>
```

If you save the .html file and drag it into a browser, the tab switching works, but if I host it on Github pages, the tab switching breaks.

I followed the turtorial on w3 school:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp

Comment: Check the console, you have several mixed content warnings (ie you're trying to load a resource over `http://` from a `https://` site)

Comment: @Rory Yea, I rarely check the console. The fact it existed completely slipped me mind. I am still very new to web development. Thanks for the heads up, I will look at console more often.

Comment: not more often, I can't live without console while developing @Dobob , always stick to console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://theonlywei.github.io/' was loaded over 
HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 
'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'. This 
request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

It helps to open the console sometimes, you need to use:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

So you have to find that `<script>` tag where you import bootstrap.js and correct the url to `https`

Comment: Oh wow, I would have never caught the bug. Still learning web development and never bothered with console. Thanks for the heads-up, I will check the console from now on.